# Ubuntu 17.04 Wifi connection degrades over time. Resetting switch corrects issue temporarily

Tags: wireless, 17.04

So I'm running 17.04 Ubuntu Budgie on a Dell Latitude E6410. It works great and Wifi worked fine after install (no other drivers needed) but after a short while the wifi will just completely stop. The signal meter in the bar shows the signal has dropped to less than 30% and nothing will load. If I turn the wifi switch on the side of the laptop off and then on again everything comes back in a few seconds and the meter shows it's full strength.

Comment: Is there another live OS you could try? Something to isolate whether it is a hardware or software issue?

Comment: I can try a vanilla 17.04 live later on this evening. This Laptop was using Windows 7 with no issues about 2 weeks ago.

Comment: That's usually a pretty good benchmark

Comment: just did a 17.04 vanilla live and had similar issues. Wifi would slow down incredibly but not completely stop.

Comment: That leaves two possibilities: a problem with Ubuntu's handling of wireless or a new hardware problem. You could eliminate the second option by making a Windows live CD and seeing if the network behaves as expected: https://www.technorms.com/8098/create-windows-7-live-cd

Comment: I loaded a 2nd hard drive up with Win 7 and had no issues with Wifi. This seems to be solely connected with 17.04